# OpenSea API "only_opensea"

Tags: api, blockchain, opensea

Looking at OpenSea's API, Retreiving Events:

https://docs.opensea.io/reference/retrieving-asset-events

`only_opensea`

is a boolean that can be `true/false`

The API description is:

**"Restrict to events on OpenSea auctions. Can be true or false"**

Does anyone know exactly what this does?

If true, does it only return OpenSea Auctions...

And if false, returns all events (auctions or not)?

Comment: I think it means events on other marketplaces.